# Have the same lambda configurations for multiple events in cloudFormation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing a CloudFormation code to create and configure an S3 bucket.
As part of the configuration, I'm adding a lambda triggering in 2 events. It's the same lambda.
How can I write this code? Should I duplicate the section or can I map the two events to the same behavior?

Here is the code

```
MyBucket:
    Condition: CreateNewBucket
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    ## ...Bucket Config comes here... ##

    ## The interesting part ##
    NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:Put'
            Function: My Lambda name
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: 'someValue'
```

Is there an option to write:

```
LambdaConfigurations:
          - Events: ['s3:ObjectCreated:Put', 's3:ObjectCreated:Post']
```

Or maybe

```
LambdaConfigurations:
          - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:Put',
          - Event 's3:ObjectCreated:Post',
          ...
```

Or Do I need to copy-past the block twice?
I can't find an example for this behavior.

Sorry if this is a trivial question, I'm new to CloudFormation.

Thanks!

Comment: `s3:ObjectCreated:*`!?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you want to trigger the lambda function. If you want the event to fire on all object create events (`s3:ObjectCreated:Put`, `s3:ObjectCreated:Post`, `s3:ObjectCreated:copy`, and `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload`), you can simply use `'s3:ObjectCreated:*'` as the value for Event.

If you want `Put` and `Post` specifically, you'll need to supply two event configurations, one for `Put` and another for `Post`. The CloudFormation parser will accept multiple `Event` elements in a `LambdaConfiguration` but only the last one to appear is applied to the event notification.

This is an interesting divergence in console/API functionality vs CloudFormation/CDK functionality. The `PutBucketNotificationConfiguration` API operation accepts [`LambdaFunctionConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_LambdaFunctionConfiguration.html) arguments that support multiple individual events. `PutBucketNotificationConfiguration` replaces PutBucketNotification, which accepted [`CloudFunctionConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CloudFunctionConfiguration.html), which has a deprecated `Event` element. So I wonder if CloudFormation still refers to the older API operation.